# extracting recurring pattern with regular expressions

Tags: c#, regex

I have some text where a list of (id (in the form Pnumber) , a dash and a name) are written.
like in:

```
P1 - code23
P2 - name asd, P3 -name3
P3 - 837/55 P5 - code/55
```

as you see the couples PX - name can be divided by \n, comma,or simple spaces.

with the regexp pattern

```
(((?<id>P\d)(\s)?-(\s)?(?<name>(.)*)(,)?(\n)?))
```

I can extract the name group of matches repeated on different lines, but not the one divided by , or space.
the names extracted from the text above are

```
code23 (right)
name asd, P3 -name3 (wrong)
837/55 P5 - code/55 (wrong)
```

How can I modify my pattern?

Comment: Singleline mode `(?<id>P\d)(\s?-\s?)(?<name>.*?)(\s|,|\.|\n|$)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try

```
(?<id>P\d+)\s*-\s*(?<name>.*?)(?=$|,?\s*P\d)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3Cid%3EP%5Cd%2B)%5Cs*-%5Cs*(%3F%3Cname%3E.*%3F)(%3F%3D%5Cr%3F%24%7C%2C%3F%5Cs*P%5Cd)&i=P1%20-%20code23%0D%0AP2%20-%20name%20asd%2C%20P3%20-name3%0D%0AP3%20-%20837%2F55%20P5%20-%20code%2F55&o=m) (`\r?` added in the demo only because multiline mode is on and the input is multiline, if the strings are handled separately, no `\r?` and multiline mode are necessary).

*Explanation*:

- `(?<id>P\d+)` -Group ID, `P` + 1+ digits
- `\s*-\s*` - 0+ whitespaces, `-` and again 0+ whitespaces
- `(?<name>.*?)` - Group NAME that captures 0+ chars other than newline up to the first
- `(?=$|,?\s*P\d)` - end of string (yes, the only one) or an optional comma, 0+ whitespaces, `P` and a digit.

Results:

[image]